# Next steps in searching extracted data from web crawler

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler, text-mining

I've just gotten my web crawler/scraper to bring back the text I want, but now I'd love to search the lines and bring back only certain lines with specific words in them.

I think I need to split the strings? But this is where I've gotten lost. Test_2 pulls the body from the HTML page.

Here is my attempt to pull certain lines from Test_2 that contain certain words/phrases:

```
import Test_2

def main():

    html_page = Test_2.string(text)
    date = "M-F"
    results = html_page.search(date)
    print(results)

main()
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions, guidance, or help!

Comment: What does your `Test_2` do?

Comment: This question is vague. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. What are you parsing for? What is the immediate output you get that you are trying to parse? I assume it is a string? Do you really need the entire top code block for us to help you? In short: what are your inputs, what are your intended outputs, and what other constraints do you have?

Comment: I've edited my questions a little bit to help simplify! I can see how that was very vauge and lengthy. Thank you!!